# Counting in Lojban, The numbers from zero to nine are: 0 no 1 pa 2 re 3 ci 4 vo 5 mk 6 xa 7 ze 8 bi 9

Tags: java

Counting in Lojban, an artificial language developed over 
the last forty years, is easier than in most languages
The numbers from zero to nine are:

```
0  no
1  pa
2  re
3  ci
4  vo
5  mk
6  xa
7  ze
8  bi
9  so
```

Larger numbers are created by gluing the digit together.
For example, 123 is "pareci".
Write a program that reads in a lojban string (representing 
a no. less than or equal to 1,000,000) and output it in 
numbers.

I don't know what happened; it seems that my programme is not checking the if statement       `if (str.substring(i-2,i) == q[ale])`.  The rest of the loop is working fine.  Any advice?

```
public class apple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] q =
           new String[10];//"no","pa","re","ci","vo","mk","xa","ze","bi","so"];
        q[0] = "no";
        q[1] = "pa";
        q[2] = "re";
        q[3] = "so";
        q[4] = "ci";
        q[5] = "vo";
        q[6] = "mk";
        q[7] = "xa";
        q[8] = "ze";
        q[9] = "bi";

        //q[0] = "so";
        int ln;

        String str = "nocipa";
        ln = str.length();

        if (ln % 2 != 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid number");
        }
        else
        { 
            for (int i = 2; i <=ln-2; i = i + 2)
            {
                for (int ale = 0; ale < 9; ale++)
                {
                    if (str.substring(i-2,i) == q[ale])
                    {
                        System.out.print("hello" ); 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, testing that the length of the string is even is *not* a sufficient test for whether it's a valid number or not.  Necessary, but not sufficient.

Comment: And there is an inconsistency in the declared list of numbers: 3 is "ci" (in your explanation) or "so" (in your code)?

Answer (score 1):

As @Makoto stated, and as [that question explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) using == is *not* the way to compare strings. Instead use

```
str.substring(i-2,i).equals(q[ale]);
```

`==` operator will return `true` if both sides refer to the same object. Not if the objects are equal.